# Rails 3 backend on Heroku, website and email on bluehost?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, dns, bluehost

Okay, here's the situation. I've had a bluehost account for several years and am happy enough with it I'm unwilling to move without a really good reason. However, I'm finding more and more that the best solution to the main use for one of my domains is to have a fairly simple rails app running to cover that.

The rails app could easily be front-ended by two forms on the landing page, each with a couple of follow-up pages, but I want the URL always to show "mysite.com" rather than "myapp.heroku.com". I also want to continue to use my email addresses with this site. I don't expect the app to see heavy usage, and am unlikely to go over the 750 hr/mo free time on heroku.

I currently use Rails 3, and would likely have trouble stepping back to rails 2 in my thinking. I'm also not very good at programming in rails, or anything else for that matter, so I'd like not to confuse myself any more than necessary.

So what's my solution here? Transfer the whole domain to Heroku? Embed partials of the app in the landing page? Can I keep email addresses working with Heroku? Can I transfer just the www.mysite.com to heroku, but have everything else involved with the domain hit bluehost?

I'm open to advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku doesn't provide any email hosting/sending itself - so you either bring your own or use one of the Heroku addons like SendGrid for sending mail from your application.

Of course, you can just leave you email etc with Bluehost provided that you can modify the DNS  and change your www record to be a CNAME to proxy.heroku.com (after you've added the custom domain addon to your Heroku application)

Comment: So if I read this correctly @JohnBeynon, I need to CNAME 'www.mysite.com' to 'appname.heroku.com' (after adding on custom domain) and I can leave my email at 'mysite.com'?

Comment: no, you always cname to proxy.heroku.com and then add the custom domain add on and then add your www.mysite.com to your application - http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains covers it in more details. But yes, you can leave your email where it is.

Comment: Terrific! Thank you! Just poked around the bluehost DNS tools and found that should be pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with blue host and heroku where I hosted my app on heroku and wanted to keep email on blue host.  I am using DNS Made easy so your mileage may vary but I had to create an A record pointing to the ip address 69.89.31.63,  you name the A record mail.yourdomain.com
and then create an mx record pointing to 69.89.31.63.  I am on the cedar stack.